# Query All Subscribers Unsub Status within Child BU?

Tags: marketing-cloud

An account I'm working in is set-up to do sending to data extensions and is also configured to capture unsubscribes at a business unit level. Have a request to provide a more accurate picture of the "sendable" audience (i.e., excluding unsubscribed or held records). Running a query activity against the _subscribers data view to retrieve Status only seems to produce results when done at the enterprise level, which does not reflect those unsubscribes being held at the child bu level. Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior?  Other than doing a manual search by status and then exporting out results from the bu level all subscribers and reimporting into a DE to query against does anyone have a workaround?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: This is a dirty little ExactTarget secret...you can't get a 2.0 business unit subscriber status from a system data view or via API.   The only decent solution I've seen involved tracking extracts from each business unit written to a shared data extension as Timothy suggested below.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like this is a pretty big hole in 2.0 functionality.  At least using a Tracking Extract and importing to a shared DE will allow me to set up something that can be run in an automated fashion.

Comment: This thread was from 3+ years ago -- is this "Dirty Little Secret" still true?
Is there any way to query for the child BU subscription status via SQL activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _subscribers view is viewing the All Subscribers list, and there is only one AllSubs list across all BU's, so this is expected behavior.  A potential workaround might be to use a shared DE's somehow, which you could use to aggregate data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could also ask to Service Team to build a custom view for you that will get the status from all children BU and expose it a SQL Query activity. It has been done successfully in the past.